# W3.CSS how to make container centered inside another container

Tags: css

I'm using the w3.css, I wanted to make a colored background with width 100%,
and inside it another box with width 80% which will contain the text, so I used the following:

```
<div class="w3-container w3-light-green">
<div class="w3-container w3-sand w3-center" style="width:80%">
test
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the second container with the 80% width is not centered in the page although I used w3-center.
I noticed that w3-center only centers the text, but the container itself isn't centered, so how can I center the container block?

Comment: Could you provide at least a work from you so we can help you what is wrong in your code?

Comment: I edited my post now

Comment: add fiddle or snippet code so we could help u out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work.. Try It..

```
<div class="w3-container w3-light-green">
<div class="w3-container w3-sand w3-center" style="width:80%;margin:auto;">
test
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

W3.CSS has no class for centring block elements. The only classes which do that have other effects as well.

You'll need to set the left and right margins to auto yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about w3.css there could be a native solution to this but If you prefer hacky way there it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-light-green" style="text-align: center">
<div class="w3-container w3-sand w3-center" style="width:80%; display: inline-block;">
test
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2j676ba/

Comment: Haters gonna hate. Respect to answers If you don't find it useful then explain why before you downvote

Comment: Thanks all for your help, it's my very first time here in stackoverflow so I dont know much here, but I didnt downvote anybody, I just accpeted one answer as it worked with my problem.

Comment: I did not mention you or anybody. I'm glad you solved your problem. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<html> <div class="w3-container w3-light-green">
   <div class="w3-container w3-sand w3-center justify-content-md-center" style="width:80%">
test
   </div>
</div>`
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**w3-auto** is a container for responsive size centered content.

**w3-content** is a container for fixed size centered content.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_references.asp

w3-auto is

```
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I suggest

```
<div class="w3-container w3-light-green">
    <div class="w3-container w3-sand w3-auto" style="width:80%">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to center the text, use also w3-center, of course.